# When user propose new time in google calendar events is their any way to know that via API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

Currently there is no key in response object fetched via get event API to identify that new time has beed proposed by user!

How would i know that this user has proposed new time ?

```
            "kind": "calendar#event",
            "etag": "\".............\"",
            "id": "XYZ",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=XYZ",
            "created": "2020-10-22T14:29:07.000Z",
            "updated": "2020-10-22T14:31:34.636Z",
            "summary": "..................",
            "description": "....................",
            "location": "................",
            "creator": {
                "email": "xyx@gmail.com",
                "self": true
            },
            "organizer": {
                "email": "bot@xyz.co",
                "displayName": "................."
            },
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2020-10-23T06:00:00+05:30"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2020-10-23T06:15:00+05:30"
            },
            "iCalUID": "...........................",
            "sequence": 0,
            "attendees": [
                {
                    "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
                    "self": true,
                    "responseStatus": "tentative"
                }
            ],
            "guestsCanInviteOthers": false,
            "privateCopy": true,
            "reminders": {
                "useDefault": true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately it is currectly not possible

On Google  Issue Tracker, there is already a  [related Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/170465098).

Give it a "star" to increase visibility and hopefully reduce implementation time.